# No converter found capable of converting from type [java.util.LinkedHashMap<?, ?>] to type [com.csc.gts.model.entity]

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I'm currently doing a MongoDB + spring boot project and got some trouble when I create the mapping.
In my model, there is one class called AllocRequests:

```java
public class AllocRequests {

    @Field("ShipmentAllocRequest")
    private ShipmentAllocRequest shipmentAllocRequest;

    public AllocRequests() {}

    public AllocRequests(ShipmentAllocRequest shipmentAllocRequest) {
        this.shipmentAllocRequest = shipmentAllocRequest;
    }

    public ShipmentAllocRequest getShipmentAllocRequest() {
        return shipmentAllocRequest;
    }

    public void setShipmentAllocRequest(ShipmentAllocRequest shipmentAllocRequest) {
        this.shipmentAllocRequest = shipmentAllocRequest;
    }

}
```

But when I run the code, I will get 'org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.util.LinkedHashMap] to type [com.csc.gts.model.ShipmentAllocRequest]'

The problem is because the data's structure
I noticed that some of the 'ShipmentAllocRequest' is an object:
[ShipmentAllocRequest is an object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sfejt.png)

While others could be an Array:
[ShipmentAllocRequest is an array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQpq5.png)

I have tried to change the model class to:

```java
public class AllocRequests {

    @Field("ShipmentAllocRequest")
    private List<ShipmentAllocRequest> shipmentAllocRequest;

    public AllocRequests() {}

    public AllocRequests(List<ShipmentAllocRequest> shipmentAllocRequest) {
        this.shipmentAllocRequest = shipmentAllocRequest;
    }

    public List<ShipmentAllocRequest> getShipmentAllocRequest() {
        return shipmentAllocRequest;
    }

    public void setShipmentAllocRequest(List<ShipmentAllocRequest> shipmentAllocRequest) {
        this.shipmentAllocRequest = shipmentAllocRequest;
    }

}
```

But then I will get a new problem:
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [java.util.List]: Specified class is an interface

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: I have two questions, how are you inserting the data into the MongoDB and how are you fetching it?

Comment: @MarcosBarbero Hi Marcos, thanks for asking the background story. I got a JSON file at first, then I write some scripts to insert these JSON records into the MongoDb